Macro needs to run twice to get all data
The below Import data from wb2.Sh3. section works fine and that data it imports one of the cells is required to import the Import data from wb.Sh2. section so for some reason its not updating properly first to do this import in the same run. It works fine after I run it a second time though.
Is there anything I can do to make it update and run second section in the same run.
Thanks Todd
Option Explicit ' at the top of each module
Sub Autofill()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Excel.Workbooks("testing (version 2).xlsm") ' workbook containing this code
Dim wb2 As Excel.Workbook

On Error Resume Next
Set wb2 = Excel.Workbooks("Job Nos.xlsx")

If Err <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\Job Nos.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Excel.Workbooks("Job Nos.xlsx")
    Windows("testing (version 2).xlsm").Activate
End If

Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = wb.Sheets("Certificates") '<-The sheet that you test B for TRUE
Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = wb.Sheets("Codes") '<- The sheet for the vlookup range
Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = wb2.Sheets("Jobs")
Dim MyVariable As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = Sh2.Range("A2", Sh2.Cells(Sh2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Dim jslrg As Range: Set jslrg = Sh3.Range("A2", Sh3.Cells(Sh3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slrg.EntireRow
Dim jsrg As Range: Set jsrg = jslrg.EntireRow
Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Sh1.Range("B2", Sh1.Cells(Sh1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
Dim jdrg As Range: Set jdrg = Sh1.Range("I2", Sh1.Cells(Sh1.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
    
    
    ' Import data from wb2.Sh3.
    Dim bcell As Range, aRow As Variant
    For Each bcell In jdrg.Cells
        With bcell.EntireRow
            If bcell.Value > 0 And .Columns("E").Value = 0 Then
                aRow = Application.Match(bcell.Value, jslrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(aRow) Then
                    .Columns("G").Value = jsrg.Rows(aRow).Columns("B").Value
                    .Columns("H").Value = jsrg.Rows(aRow).Columns("C").Value
                    .Columns("B").Value = jsrg.Rows(aRow).Columns("D").Value
                Else
                    .Columns("G").Value = ""
                    .Columns("H").Value = ""
                    .Columns("B").Value = ""
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next bcell

' ***It completes the above section which enters data that the below needs to be able to complete the below but macro needs to be run a second time for that to run***

    ' Import data from wb.Sh2.
    Dim dcell As Range, sRow As Variant
    For Each dcell In drg.Cells
        With dcell.EntireRow
            If dcell.Value > 0 And .Columns("E").Value = 0 Then
                sRow = Application.Match(dcell.Value, slrg, 0)
                If IsNumeric(sRow) Then
                    .Columns("E:F").Value = srg.Rows(sRow).Columns("D:E").Value
                    .Columns("J:S").Value = srg.Rows(sRow).Columns("I:R").Value
                Else
                    .Columns("E:F").Value = ""
                    .Columns("J:S").Value = ""
                End If
                .Columns("T:DT").Value = Sh2.Range("G19:DG19").Value
            End If
        End With
    Next dcell

Dim LR_B As Single
LR_B = Sh1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim LR_A As Single
LR_A = Sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Sh1.Range("A" & LR_A).Select
    If (LR_B - LR_A) > 0 Then
        Selection.Autofill Destination:=Sh1.Range("A" & LR_A & ":A" & LR_B)
    End If
    Sh1.Range("A" & LR_B).Select
End Sub


How about putting Application.Calculate between the two sections in question?

Nope still doesn't complete until I run it twice

If Job Nos workbook is open then your On Error Resume Next line stays active as no error occurs.  Comment that line out and see if an error occurs in your code block that isn't running.

It didn't work before I added any of that job nos open code that was the last bit of code I added in after i realised Job nos had to be open for it to run

I suspect you should be calculating the end row number for the second range after you run the first section?

Thank you very much. Yes I had that in too early now it works. Only been learning this for the last week still plenty to learn about the order it does things, makes sense though.

Side note: if you go "Tools" → "Options" → "Editor", you can turn on the "Require Variable Declaration" option to automatically add Option Explicit to the top of new Modules you create
